# shift+arrow for org-mode

Tags: org-mode, use-package

https://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html#index-windmove_002eel

says

```
;; Make windmove work in Org mode:
(add-hook 'org-shiftup-final-hook 'windmove-up)
(add-hook 'org-shiftleft-final-hook 'windmove-left)
(add-hook 'org-shiftdown-final-hook 'windmove-down)
(add-hook 'org-shiftright-final-hook 'windmove-right)
```

I try to add to one of `(use-package org` or `(use-package windmove`
to keep init.el organized.

How should I put them inside `use-package` ?

Comment: Make sure you understand the first source block [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks). Then, I guess you will conclude that you can put them wherever you prefer (although I am not sure if you would ever need to configure windmove via use-package, so probably put them in the 'org' one).